# How to append file in formData object without physically saving file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, file, blob, multer, form-data

I am trying to work on an application to upload a file from react to NodeJs. Once upload running few validations from multer and then again sending the file as part of multipart/form-data to another API. I am failing to use the uploaded file to append in the formData as below.

```
  router.post("/upload", uploadAndScan.any("filename"), (req, res) => {
    scanFiles(req.files[0])
      .then((data) => {
        global.logger.info("scanned successfully.....");
        res.status(200);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        global.logger.info("scan api ended with errors", err);
        res.status(400).send({ error: err.message })
      });
  });
```

My scanFiles function looks like

```
import FormData from "form-data";
export function scanFiles(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const hrstart = process.hrtime();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file), "sample_pdf.pdf"); // Getting error in this line
```

I am getting an error for the last line as it is expecting a usvstring or Blob but I am unable to provide any. I cannot save the file to disk as it may have some virus. I am looking to see if there is a way to convert either file to Blob or some other way to append the file in the formData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the file Blob/Buffer in `file.buffer` if you're using multer with `MemoryStorage` (which is the default). All available file properties are documented here: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information.

This [Request Parsing in Node.js Guide](https://maximorlov.com/request-parsing-nodejs-guide/) (it's free) will help you with file uploads in Node.js.

Comment: Thank you. Its working. At least my request is getting created successfully. Was looking for this exact answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked , good luck with your project!